# Android studio SDK manager disabled in configuration window

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have recently installed the Android studio and open, then went to the configure section to configure the SDK manager, but it is not active in here as below image I have already updated to the latest version of Android Studio, how to fix this

[image: enter code here]

Comment: `how to fix this` ==> `Avoid the message`

Comment: try creating a new project and then start the sdk manager when android studio loads your project

Answer (score 0):

It disables the SDK manager if you don't have an SDK set up to manage. From that screen, go **Project Defaults > Project Structure > SDK Location** and point Android Studio to your Android SDK and JDK.